# Single shortcut to forward search after Ctrl-R reverse search

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> all the time, but I often end up going past the command I'm after as I'm pressing it so quickly.

To forward search, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> can be used provided it's not used the terminal first (konsole in my case, in which `stty -ixon` in `~/.bashrc` fixes it).

However, I have to press it twice: once it seems to enter `i-search` after being in `reverse-i-search` mode and a second time to actually step backwards.

Is there a way to remove the need for pressing the shortcut twice?

Comment: As with Ctrl-R, the first Ctrl-S waits for a string to search. The second one reuse the same search string you used before (with Ctrl-R in your situation). I know of no way to avoid those two steps. `readline` lacks a "search the same string the other way round" function.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a different approach. If you are comfortable with some basic vi editing commands, bash supports a vi-mode for command line editing. If you really hate vi you won't like this. But if you can tolerate it, you may find it preferable and with fewer keystrokes.

set -o vi

History search works like this:

- `Esc` to enter command mode
- `/` to begin search
- Type text of search string
- `Enter` to perform search
- `n` to go to next match
- `N` to jump back to the previous match
- `i` to get back into insert mode
- `Enter` to run command

Comment: The vi-style equivalents to Ctrl-R and Ctrl-S are `n` and `N`, respectively. And they don't require tapping twice. Intriguing!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the Bash history search requires a first press of the shortcut to let you know which direction you're searching, then a second press to actually perform the search. I don't think is possible to change the way it works without modifying the source code.

However, you can install [**hstr** (https://github.com/dvorka/hstr)](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr) which features a suggest box with advanced search options to easily view, navigate, search, and manage your command history:

[image]